# UIScrollView and UIButton are not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I have a UIButton and UIScrollView on my ViewControl (both of which are arranged to the very top of the ViewController) I also have a UIWebView that is full width and height of the ViewController (it is set to the very back) 

Here's the code from the .m file, it includes the animations, constraints and UIwebView url requests.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView2;
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    draw1 = 0;

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 480, 55);

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 55)];



    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);

    // stuff************************************************************************************************************************






    [super viewDidLoad];



            UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];




    NSString *url=@"http://test.bithumor.co/test26.php";



    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];



    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];



    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];



    [self.view addSubview:webview];

    webview.scrollView.bounces = NO;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIWebView *webview2=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];

    NSString *url2=@"http://google.com";

    NSURL *nsurl2=[NSURL URLWithString:url2];

    NSURLRequest *nsrequest2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl2];

    [webview2 loadRequest:nsrequest2];

    webview2.scrollView.bounces = NO;





        // stuff************************************************************************************************************************
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    draw1 = 1;

}



- (IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender {

    if (draw1 ==0) {

        draw1 = 1;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5

                              delay:0.0

                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut


                         animations:^{

                             scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1000, 568, 200);

                             openMenu.layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 27, self.view.frame.size.height - 80, 80, 80);

                         }

                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                             NSLog(@"Done!");

                         }];

    } else {

        draw1 = 0;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5

                              delay:0.0

                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut

                         animations:^{

                             scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 568, 200);

                             openMenu.layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - 23, 220, 80, 80);

                         }

                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                             NSLog(@"Done!");

                         }];

    }

}


@end
```

*The issue is that only the UIwebView is visible (full screen) when I run the app in the simulator*

**How do I make it so the UIscrollView and UIButton are visible above the UIwebView?**

Comment: you never added the button or the scrollview. You need to add that before your [self.view addSubview:webview];

Comment: the button is `openMenu`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of viewDidLoad, try to bring scroll and button to front

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:webview];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront: openMenu];
```

Comment: Result: UIwebView does not load webpage.

Comment: "Result: UIwebView does not load webpage" What does that mean?

Comment: That's what happened after I added the code from your answer and ran the app in the simulator. The webpage in the UIwebView didn't load.

Comment: webview2 you use for what? I think webview loaded but it is in the back of something

Comment: It is for anther WebView in a different ViewController

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView; it connected with a webview in nib file right? You create it by drag drop in IB. ?

Comment: No, it is in the main.storyboard